# OpenCV - Closing a contour against image edge

Tags: python, opencv

How can I highly accurately find the area of smooth surfaces. I am  trying to find areas of bubbles in a cylinder.

This code works relatively well, but does not provide the area for the open surfaces.

It also finds a fake bubble (which you can see if running the code)

Image:

[image]

Is there a way to make the edge of the image the end point of the contour?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

image = cv2.imread('Image.png')

# Convert Image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
(thresh, bw) = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Show greyscale image
cv2.namedWindow("main", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('main', bw)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print("no of shapes {}".format(len(contours)))
for c in cnts: 
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 0:
    # compute the center of the contour
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

        # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255,0,0), -1)
        cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 2)

        # show the image
        cv2.namedWindow("main", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("main", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        print(area)
```

I have full flexibility in the output of the image (colour of the lines, background colour, line thickness) as the output is from simulations.

What settings would work best for OpenCV?